# how to read html tag with values in java

Tags: java, jsoup

I want the output like this

```
tag=value
```

like this `(body=hello)`

```
String html="<html><body><div class=\"main\">" + "<div class=\"sub\"> sub </div>" + "main </div></body></html>";

Document doc=Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements divs=doc.select("div");
for(Element div : divs){
System.out.println(div.ownText());
}
```

Comment: Where is the output? Please make it elaborate and clear

Comment: Do you want to render this code in your html?

Comment: I gues you need the DOM librarie :))

Comment: read multiple times but not clear, what you want

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is to show each tag name and the content in it. The sample code is like this.

```
    String html="<html><body><div class=\"main\">" + "<div class=\"sub\"> sub </div>" + "main </div></body></html>";
    Document doc=Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements divs=doc.select("*");
    for(Element div : divs){
        System.out.println(div.tag() + ":\n" + div.toString());
        System.out.println("---");
    }
```

The result shows this.

```
    #root:
    <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
      <div class="main">
       <div class="sub">
         sub 
       </div>main 
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
    ---
    html:
    <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
      <div class="main">
       <div class="sub">
         sub 
       </div>main 
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
    ---
    head:
    <head></head>
    ---
    body:
    <body>
     <div class="main">
      <div class="sub">
        sub 
      </div>main 
     </div>
    </body>
    ---
    div:
    <div class="main">
     <div class="sub">
       sub 
     </div>main 
    </div>
    ---
    div:
    <div class="sub">
      sub 
    </div>
    ---
```